# Получение данных за последний месяц из БД с помощью ORM peewee на python

Tags: python-3.x, orm, peewee

Начинаю работу с ORM peewee на python, у меня есть таблица с полем date = DateTimeField(), мне необходимо выгружать из данной таблицы все записи у которых столбец "date" равен предыдущему месяцу.

```
class Jobs(BaseModel):
    date = DateTimeField()
    user_id = ForeignKeyField(Users)
    service_id = ForeignKeyField(Services)
    comment = TextField()
```

Обычный SQL запрос я делаю так:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE date_part('month', date) = date_part('now', 'start of month');
```

По инструкции в peewee это делается, с помощью `fn.date_part`, но не совсем понимаю как это использовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать данный запрос в peewee?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, должно получиться так:

```
import datetime as DT

# Предыдущий месяц
prev_month = DT.date.today().replace(day=1) - DT.timedelta(days=1)

query = Jobs.select().where(fn.date_part('month', Jobs.date) == prev_month.month)
```

Думаю, лучше добавить в условие год:

```
query = Jobs.select().where(
    (fn.date_part('month', Jobs.date) == prev_month.month)
    & (fn.date_part('year', Jobs.date) == prev_month.year)
)
```

<kbd>!</kbd> Кст, `peewee` сам может в `date_part` обернуть условия в запросе, поэтому попробуйте так:

```
query = Jobs.select().where(
    (Jobs.date.month == prev_month.month) & (Jobs.date.year == prev_month.year)
)
```

Делал на основе [примера](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html#list-the-total-slots-booked-per-facility-per-month)